# ошибка при сохранении данных в XML-файл

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, сериализация

У меня есть класс

```
public class InfoPerson
    {
        public string FIO { set; get; }
        public string Gender { set; get; }
        public string YearOfBirth { set; get; }

        public InfoPerson(string fio, string gender, string yearOfBirth)
        {
            FIO = fio;
            Gender = gender;
            YearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        }      
    }
```

Есть DataGrid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные в DataGrid заполняю через DataBinding. После когда данные заполнены, мне нужно их сохранить в XML-файл по закрытию данной формы. И по открытию, чтобы данные подгружались с файла.

Пробовал такой код:

```
List<InfoPerson> infoPerson = new List<InfoPerson>();
        public void SaveFile()
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<InfoPerson>));
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("infopersons.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, infoPerson);
            }
        }
```

Но выдает исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу разобраться в чем причина, кто подскажет что я делаю не так?

Вроде разобрался, такой код работает

```
public BindingList<InfoPerson> InfoPerson { get; set; } = new BindingList<InfoPerson>();
public void Save(string FileName)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(FileName))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(InfoPerson.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(writer, InfoPerson);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Comment: [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBOMV.png)?

Comment: понял, добавил конструктор без параметров, файлик создает, но он пустой, точнее все что в нем есть <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfInfoPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

Comment: ну то есть вы сохраняете пустой список

Comment: я кажется понял, нужно сохранять не список обьектов класа, а биндинглист который биндится к датагриду и выводит данные, так вроде как работает

Comment: нужно сохранять так, чтобы протом можно было прочитать. Я бы сохранял `List<>`, но перед тем как его сохранить, надо в него данные добавить

Comment: а как я в него добавлю данные, если у меня данные в датагрид добавляются черездочернюю форму с текстбоксами, в которые ввожу инфу? я редактировал вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста на мое решение и на сколько оно правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описываем класс, что нам надо

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Пример нехитрой формы

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    DataGridView gv;

    public MyForm()
    {
        gv = new DataGridView();
        var bl = new BindingList<Person>();
        bl.Add(new Person() {Name = ";flkjsdflsd"});
        gv.DataSource = bl;

        this.Controls.Add(gv);

        var bt = new Button() {Text = "Save", Left = 250};
        bt.Click+= (sender, args) => {

            using(var sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\temp\out.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                ser.Serialize(sw, bl.ToList());
            }           
        };

        this.Controls.Add(bt);
    }
}
```

Запуск

```
new MyForm().ShowDialog();
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Форма вместе со считыванием.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    DataGridView gv;

    public MyForm()
    {
        gv = new DataGridView();
        var bl = new BindingList<Person>();
        bl.Add(new Person() { Name = ";flkjsdflsd" });
        gv.DataSource = bl;

        this.Controls.Add(gv);

        var bt = new Button() { Text = "Save", Left = 250 };
        bt.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\temp\out.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                ser.Serialize(sw, bl.ToList());
            }
        };

        this.Controls.Add(bt);


        bt = new Button() { Text = "Load", Left = 250, Top = 50 };
        bt.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\temp\out.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                var list = (List<Person>)ser.Deserialize(sr);
                bl.Clear();

                foreach (var p in list) bl.Add(p);
            }
        };

        this.Controls.Add(bt);
    }
}
```

Comment: хорошее решение, а если мне нужно по закрытию формы чтобы сохраняло, этот кусок кода using(var sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\temp\out.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
                ser.Serialize(sw, bl.ToList());
            }         нужно поместить в событие Form_Closed?

Comment: @erleug не попробуете - не узнаете :)

Comment: @erleug вы задали конкретный вопрос наверху, я вам на него ответил. Если у вас какой то другой вопрос, то задавайте его отдельно.

Comment: спасибо) этот вопрос у меня в этой теме)) есть конечно и еще один про дисериализацию, если можно понаглеть?)

Comment: @erleug а какие проблемы с десериализацией?

Comment: как его считать теперь с сохраненного файла после открытия формы? извиняюсь за такие вопросы, опыта с этим практически не было

Comment: @erleug добавил считывание в ответ

Comment: огромное вам спасибо!) только вопрос, вес работает, но почему когда сохранил все данные, и при повторном запуске формы в датагрид подтягивает в конец "лишнюю" строку с обьекта, который мы тут создаем bl.Add(new Person() { Name = ";flkjsdflsd" }); как этого избежать? чтобы при повторном перезаходе, выводило теже данные при последнем закрытии без этой строки?

Comment: @erleug так удалите эту строку :)

Comment: капец, вы мне за пол часа в многократно раз подняли знания в сериализации и дисериализации, большой вам респект)) жаль немогу проголосовать за ваши комменты

Comment: @erleug значит и для меня, и для вас вечер прошел не зря :) удачи с приложением.